# Origin of the name jQuery

Tags: jquery

This may seem like an odd question, but does anyone know the origin of the jQuery name?  How did it come to be called "jQuery"?

Comment: Fair enough.  Changed to CW.  Not sure why the votes to close are being racked up.  It's programming-related, non-offensive and I've responded to the request to transfer ownership to the Community User.

Comment: Sorry but how is this "not a real question"?

Comment: I was kind of wondering that myself.

Comment: Why should it be CW? People have this aversion for giving people points which is beyond me. I see nothing wrong in trying to get more points especially for new users who want to have the ability to edit posts etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From John Resig himself:

> I was, originally, going to use JSelect, but all the domain names were taken already.

That was in reply to a comment from Kris De Volder, the creator of the Eclipse plugin, "JQuery" (with a capital "J"):

> Did you do a websearch before decding name you script language "JQuery"? There are in fact already two other thing that are called JQuery out there.

Source: **http://ejohn.org/blog/barcampnyc-wrap-up/** (see the comments)

Comment: Dean Edwards’ cssQuery (see http://dean.edwards.name/my/cssQuery/) might also had an influence on the name (see http://www.slideshare.net/jeresig/history-of-jquery).

Answer (score 14):

As I understand it, it is because it gives you a way to 'query' the DOM using the selectors.  The 'j' is for Javascript

Comment: as opposed to uppercase J that relates to Java.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured but I'm being asked for a verifiable source that I can quote.  It seems that everyone just assumes (most likely correctly) that it's due to the queryable nature of the DOM.

Comment: Don't most of the querying features come from the sizzle JS selector library?

Comment: @karim, before Sizzle was created jQuery used its own selector engine.

Comment: @karim79 - now they do, although jQuery was originally conceived to do just this one thing.  Sizzle didn't come along until jQuery 1.3.  See The History of jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/History_of_jQuery.  No mention there that I could see of where the name came from, but it seems to have had that name from the beginning.