# Why jQuery is called jQuery? What is the name reason?

Tags: jquery

I know ***j*** in ***jQuery*** stands for JavaScript but what about ***query*** in ***jQuery*** ? What does that stand for ?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534475/origin-of-the-name-jquery

Comment: blog article about this: http://relfor.co/article/Why-jQuery-is-called-jQuery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John Resig's reply to someone claiming the name "JQuery" for a project already:

> I was, originally, going to use
>   JSelect, but all the domain names were
>   taken already. I then did a search
>   before I decided to call the project
>   jQuery, saw your project, and also saw
>   that it hadn't been updated since
>   "October 26, 2004: JQuery 3.1.3". So,
>   I assumed it was defunct.

See http://ejohn.org/blog/barcampnyc-wrap-up/#comment-1927

Answer (score 12):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query

jQuery is -- at it's root -- about finding dom objects (using selectors) and manipulating them. You're *querying* the DOM for elements.

Comment: the question is:

... the j is for John (John Resig, the founder of the script) ?

or 

j as in "Javascript" ?

Comment: Link should be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/jQuery

Comment: @Obalix Actually, he's really asking for a definition of query in general, so I thought that was more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I presume it has to do with the fact that it's often used to query the DOM, via selectors and so forth.